# How Do I install Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows

Now the time has come for me to quit. I am not able to manage with Ubuntu, I should not blame the developers rather I should blame myself for not understanding.
I would humbly request the experts to help me in the following

1. I have a windows ISO package downloaded and stored on the desktop.
2. Please help me to create a boot-able USB of the Windows OS.
3. Please help me in finding the right application to create a boot-able USB from Ubuntu (I don't have any alternative system, not alternative OS installed or nothing.
4. I am really stuck with this.. please help me to survive by installing Windows.